# Matrices - How to compute reflectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was looking at this http://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/watkins/pdfiles/francis.pdf

And this: http://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/watkins/slides/ilas10.pdf

And it says that once you have the value of `x` you remove the zeroes and somehow create this [image]

I have x and I can compute alpha, but I'm not sure how to generate this  (3x3) reflector. I am trying to do this with code, so I'm ultimately looking for an algorithm/formula and not a "figure it out" type thing - the paper seems to suggest the existence of one with Theorem 1 but I can't figure out how to calculate the reflector.

Comment: I'm trying to find the $\tilde Q_0$ you're talking about.  I see a $Q_0$ in the slides, is that the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you mean equation (4) from the paper on page 393.  You're supposed to build $\tilde Q_0$ directly using the fact that $\tilde Q_0 x = \alpha e_1$ and **Theorem 1** on page 390.

Comment: Yea, I understand that, but I wanted to know HOW you build it? Like, I just am not getting how Q*x can equal two separate vectors. It says alpha is pos/neg ||x||*e1. How do you solve for Q?

Comment: It's not that $Qx$ is equal to both, it's that you can choose a $Q$ for either one, and it doesn't matter which you choose. To find your $Q$, plug in your choice of $\|x\|e_1$ or $-\|x\|e_1$ to the formula.